# How to upgrade to a newer version of jruby

Tags: jruby

I used the jruby zip executable to install 1.6.2, but it looks like they have released [1.6.4](http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.6.4/jruby-bin-1.6.4.zip). How should I migrate from 1.6.2 to 1.6.4, should I have to re-install or is there a different command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly all you need to do is reinstall gems on the newly-unpacked JRuby (recommended), or migrate your existing gem installs by copying the lib/ruby/gems/* over to the new location. There's no automated update tool for JRuby itself right now.

Answer (score 0):

Unpack new Jruby

```
export JRUBY_HOME=/path/to/jruby
export PATH=$PATH:$JRUBY_HOME/bin
```

Maybe even push the above to .bashrc

Add a list of required Gems to your Gemfile.

To reinstall Gems if needed the best way to do it is as follows

```
Jruby -S gem install bundler 
Cd to /path/to/Gemfile
bundle install
```

Comment: On a Windows 10 machine I had to do similar, but had to use `setx /s COMPUTER JRUBY_HOME "/path/to/jruby"` instead of the `export` command.